# How do I translate a List<string> into a SqlParameter for a Sql In statement?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqlcommand

I seem to be confused on how to perform an `In` statement with a `SqlParameter`.  So far I have the following code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select dscr from system_settings where setting in @settings";
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@settings", settingList));

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

`settingsList` is a `List<string>`. When `cmd.ExecuteReader()` is called, I get an `ArgumentException` due to not being able to map a `List<string>` to "a known provider type".

How do I (safely) perform an `In` query with `SqlCommand`s?

Comment: To what *SQL* type are you expecting your list converted?  There are no arrays...

Comment: I need the list to be a list of sql strings, for example `where setting in ('setting1', 'setting2')`

Comment: @KallDrexx, that makes no sense.  There's no such data type in SQL.  The best you can do is modify your "CommandText" to construct the desired SQL yourself (embedding the parameter values within the SQL).  It cannot be encapsulated in a `SqlParameter`.

Comment: Except that allows unsafe sql to be executed.  I find it hard to believe there's no construct to allow safe sql `in` statements

Comment: @KirkWoll, He is not trying to insert an array, the Query is a select with an intended multi valued parameter. He is trying to do something like this:

set @pCode='''A1'',''A2'',''A3'''
Exec ('Select * From Receiving Where Code In (' + @pCode + ')')

Comment: @rizzle, yes I know that.  He is trying to **pass** an array for use as the operand in his **in** expression.  That is not going to fly.

Comment: @kirk woll - as of 2008, you can pass in multiple values via table valued parameters which remove the need for the "workarounds" that were required for arrays of data in previous versions

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT dscr FROM system_settings WHERE setting IN ({0})";
string[] paramArray = settingList.Select((x, i) => "@settings" + i).ToArray();
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(sql, string.Join(",", paramArray));

for (int i = 0; i < settingList.Count; ++i)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@settings" + i, settingList[i]));
}
```

Comment: Since it's not possible to do what I wanted, I used this method.  I love linq!

Comment: This works until settingList.Count = 0, then you are going to get an error in SQL because WHERE setting IN () is invalid syntax. Table value parameter is more correct, see rizzle's answer.

Answer (score 11):

You appear to be trying to pass a multi valued parameter, that SQL syntax isn't going to do what you expect. You may want to pass a table value parameter.

Read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html#iter-list-of-strings

specifically: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#ListSqlDataRecord

```
private static void datatable_example() {

   string [] custids = {"ALFKI", "BONAP", "CACTU", "FRANK"};

   DataTable custid_list = new DataTable();
   custid_list.Columns.Add("custid", typeof(String));

   foreach (string custid in custids) {
      DataRow dr = custid_list.NewRow();
      dr["custid"] = custid;
      custid_list.Rows.Add(dr);
   }

   using(SqlConnection cn = setup_connection()) {
      using(SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand()) {

         cmd.CommandText =
           @"SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CompanyName
             FROM   Northwind.dbo.Customers C
             WHERE  C.CustomerID IN (SELECT id.custid FROM @custids id)";
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

         cmd.Parameters.Add("@custids", SqlDbType.Structured);
         cmd.Parameters["@custids"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
         cmd.Parameters["@custids"].TypeName = "custid_list_tbltype";
         cmd.Parameters["@custids"].Value = custid_list;

         using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
         using (DataSet        ds = new DataSet()) {
            da.Fill(ds);
            PrintDataSet(ds);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: surely the vitally important point you are skipping over here is the need to create the custid_list_tbltype on the database _before_ this will work

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Sql Server 2008 or later, you can make use of table valued parameters - this allows you to pass in a table of values as a parameter. From .net you define a "structured" type SqlParameter and set the value to something that implements IEnumerable.

See the full MSDN reference with examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ever use my own function to create Parameters like this:

```
public void SomeDataFunction() {    
    ArrayList params = GetParameters(someEntity);
    CommandObject.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
}

public static ArrayList GetParameters(ISomeEntity entity) {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList {                  
            OleDbUtility.NewDbParam("@Param1", OleDbType.Integer, , entity.Parameter1),
            OleDbUtility.NewDbParam("@Param2", OleDbType.VarChar, 9, entity.Parameter2),
        }
}

public static OleDbParameter NewDbParam(string parameterName, OleDbType dataType,
                    int size, object value) {
    OleDbParameter result = new OleDbParameter(parameterName, dataType, size, string.Empty);
    result.Value = value;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use XML, it's plenty fast for this scenario. You would turn your list into XML and simply pass a string:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTempTable
(   Letter VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT INTO  #myTempTable (Letter) VALUES ('A'), ('B')

Declare @xml XML = '<a>A</a><a>B</a><a>C</a>'

Select * from #myTempTable 
Where Letter in 
(Select p.value('.', 'VARCHAR(40)') AS [Letter] from @xml.nodes('//a') as t(p)) 

DROP TABLE #myTempTable
```

Comment: you have not specified how to convert list to xml.

Answer (score -3):

I usually pass in the list as a comma separated string, and then use a table valued function to 'split' the string into a table that I can then use to join with in another query.

```
DECLARE @Settings TABLE (Sid INT)   
INSERT INTO @Settings(Sid)
SELECT CAST(Items AS INT) FROM dbo.Split(@SettingsParameter, ',')
```

Unless of course you are using SQL Server 2008, then I would use the table valued parameters.