# SqlParameter and IN statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need following query:

```
createList(string commaSeparatedElements) {
    ...
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ("+commaSeparatedElements+")");
    ...
}
```

I would like to write it using a parameterized query, so every element from the string is checked to prevent against Sql-Injections.

Pseudo-code:

```
createList(string commaSeparatedElements) {
    ...
    SqlParameterList elements = new SqlParameterList("@elements", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameterList.Values = commaSeparatedElements.split(new Char[1] {','});
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (@elements)");
    query.Parameters.Add(elements);
    ...
}
```

Does anything like that exist in C#, or will I have to write it by myself?

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. As I try not to use code I don't understand (too many bad experiences in the last days), dapper and table-valued parameters, even though they may be perfect for my needs, are off-limits. I just made a loop.

```
string[] elements = commaSeparatedElements.split(new Char[1] {','});
StringList idParamList = new StringList();
for(int i=0;i<elements.Count;i++) {
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@element"+i,Convert.ToInt32(elements[i]));
    idParamList.Add("@element" + i);
}
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ("+String.Join(",",idParamList)+")");
```

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502821/how-do-i-translate-a-liststring-into-a-sqlparameter-for-a-sql-in-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a helper method like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a sequence of parameters to an existing parameter collection
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of parameter values</typeparam>
/// <param name="parameters">Existing parameter collection</param>
/// <param name="pattern">Name pattern of parameters. Must be a valid <see langword="int"/> format string</param>
/// <param name="parameterType">Database type of parameters</param>
/// <param name="length">Length of parameter. 0 for numeric parameters</param>
/// <param name="values">Sequence of values</param>
/// <returns>Comma separated string of parameter names</returns>
public static string AddParameters<T>(SqlParameterCollection parameters,
                                      string pattern,
                                      SqlDbType parameterType,
                                      int length,
                                      IEnumerable<T> values) {
    if (parameters == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parameters");
    if (pattern == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("pattern");
    if (values == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    if (!pattern.StartsWith("@", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        throw new ArgumentException("Pattern must start with '@'");

    var parameterNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in values) {
        var parameterName = parameterNames.Count.ToString(pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        parameterNames.Add(parameterName);
        parameters.Add(parameterName, parameterType, length).Value = item;
    }

    return string.Join(",", parameterNames.ToArray());
}
```

It is used like this

```
string sql = "SELECT col1 " +
             "FROM Table " +
             "WHERE col2 IN ({@Values}) ";
var paramNames = SqlHelper.AddParameters(command.Parameters,
                                         "@Value0",
                                         SqlDbType.Int,
                                         0,
                                         listOfInts);
command.CommandText = sql.Replace("{@Values}", paramNames);
...
```

(Result is a query like `SELECT ... IN (@Value0, @Value1, @Value2)`)

Answer (score 8):

["dapper"](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) has some voodoo for this:

```
var ids = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
var rows = conn.Query<SomeType>("select * from table where id in @ids",
      new { ids }).ToList();
```

You'll notice the lack of parenthesis in the `in` usage; "dapper" spots this, and performs parameter expansion automatically. Plus it handles all the command details for you, including mapping the data back into `SomeType` instances.

In the above example, it will expand to be equivalent to (approximately):

```
int ids0 = 1, ids1 = 2, ids2 = 3, ids3 = 4, ids4 = 5;
var rows = conn.Query<SomeType>(
    "select * from table where id in (@ids0,@ids1,@ids2,@ids3,@ids4)",
      new { ids0, ids1, ids2, ids3, ids4 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has one data structure that's ideal for holding multiple values of the same "type" - and that's a table.

Thankfully, in recent years, they introduced [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that you can construct a table in your client code and pass that across to the SQL Server in a natural way, e.g.:

```
// Assumes connection is an open SqlConnection.
using (connection)
{
// Create a DataTable with the modified rows.
DataTable addedCategories = CategoriesDataTable.GetChanges(
    DataRowState.Added);

// Define the INSERT-SELECT statement.
string sqlInsert = 
    "INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName)"
    + " SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName"
    + " FROM @tvpNewCategories AS nc;"

// Configure the command and parameter.
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(
    sqlInsert, connection);
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@tvpNewCategories", addedCategories);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";

// Execute the command.
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This is the best way, but caveat: TVPs can suck with stored procedures due to parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare

```
List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
```

and add there the ids you want. It's easy to convert it in a comma seperated list as follows

```
string listOfIds = string.Join(",", Ids.Select(Id => Id.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Then you pass this string as a parameter to your parameterized query.

Comment: Won't work because I don't ask `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ("1,2,3")`, I ask `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1):

which version of sql server you are using?
You should try out table value parameter if you are using sql server 2008 or later

Check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters

[Pass table valued parameter using ADO.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409576/pass-table-valued-parameter-using-ado-net)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've make in one project:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Id IN(");
        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        int i = 1;

        foreach (int item in items)
        {
            string currentItem = "@Item" + i++.ToString();
            sb.Append(currentItem + ",");
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(currentItem , item));
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length-1, 1);

        sb.Append(")");
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can put a if condition for the parameters. For Example:

```
if(commaSeparatedElements.Contains("'"))
   return;
else
   //Pass parameter & Execute query
```