# Passing List<int> as Query Parameter to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, parameter-passing

I have to pass a list to a SQL Server query using C#. My code is here:

```
using (SqlDataReader _myReader_2 = _myCommand_3.ExecuteReader())
{
    _Node_Neighbor.Clear();
        while (_myReader_2.Read())
        {
            _Node_Neighbor.Add(Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_2["Target_Node"]));
        }

    _myReader_2.Close();

  //Here I have to pass this _Node_Neighbor i.e. of type List<int> to another  
  //SQL Server query as:

    try
        {
            SqlCommand _myCommand_4 = _con.CreateCommand();

            _myCommand_4.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GraphEdges
                                         WHERE Source_Node IN @Source_Node 
                                         AND Target_Node IN @Target_Node";

            _myCommand_4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source_Node", _Node_Neighbor);
            _myCommand_4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Target_Node", _Node_Neighbor);

            _Mutual_Links = Convert.ToInt32(_myCommand_4.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
}
```

Whereas, to pass a list as a parameter, I think there might be some other way that's why I'm getting this error as:
`No mapping exists from object type Systems.Collections.Generic.List`

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to use the IN() syntax. But I'm afraid that doesn't work with parameters.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this so don't quote me on it but I _think_ there is a way to do it via stored procedures. Could be wrong. You'd have to research that yourself as I've never done it myself

Comment: Have you tried `_Node_Neighbor.ToArray()` ? I'm pretty sure parameters support arrays.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I have tried your's suggestion but got an error as: `No mapping exists from object type System.Int32[] to a known managed provider native type.`

Comment: Why not just directly format your query instead of using parameters? `string.Format("...WHERE Source_Node IN ('{0}')...", string.Join("','", _Node_Neighbor))`

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I have all of these values in integer format

Comment: It will implicitly convert the integers to strings.

Comment: Use string.join to convert the list to csv format and then your query will work e.g. select * from dummy where id in (<csv format>)

Comment: In query you have give @_Node_Neighbor as parameter, but while Adding with value you are passing @Source_Node as parameter name

Comment: @MaheshMalpani I have to select _Node_Neighbor list each time from database that's why I can't give string as a format

Comment: You can use TVP instead of passing with IN clause. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143012/sqlparameter-and-in-statement and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20143173/311255

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding multiple parameterized variables to a database in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965233/adding-multiple-parameterized-variables-to-a-database-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to pass array/list for `IN`, you have to create one parameter for each value in the list.

```
try
    {
        SqlCommand _myCommand_4 = _con.CreateCommand();


        List<string> sqlParams = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach(var value in _Node_Neighbor){
            var name = "@p"  + i++;
            _myCommand_4.Parameters.Add(name,value);
            sqlParams.Add(name);
        }

        string paramNames = string.Join(",", sqlParams);

        _myCommand_4.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GraphEdges"
                       " WHERE Source_Node IN (" + paramNames + ") " 
                         " AND Target_Node IN (" + paramNames + ")";


        _Mutual_Links = Convert.ToInt32(_myCommand_4.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you should be using string.Format in your query instead of concatenating `paramNames` to avoid sql injection.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll, `i` is integer, unnecessary string.Format is burden for simple concatenation. Sql Injection occurs only when you append non value type in sql string. There is no way in this world this can cause SQL Injection. In other answer, where values could be of non value type, that may lead to SQL Injection as they come from outside of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use **User defined table** type in `sql server` and datatable in `ADO.NET` code.

Comment: It would be good to expand on that answer. The way it is now, it's nothing more than a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Build the dynamic query in c# if array  is not large

```
using (SqlDataReader _myReader_2 = _myCommand_3.ExecuteReader())
        {
            _Node_Neighbor.Clear();
            while (_myReader_2.Read())
            {
                _Node_Neighbor.Add(Convert.ToInt32(_myReader_2["Target_Node"]));
            }

            _myReader_2.Close();

            //Here I have to pass this _Node_Neighbor i.e. of type List<int> to another  
            //SQL Server query as:

            try
            {
                var query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GraphEdges
                WHERE Source_Node IN

                (##Source_Node)

                AND Target_Node IN 
                (##Target_Node)";
                var sourceNode = "";
                foreach (var item in _Node_Neighbor)
                {
                    sourceNode += item + ",";
                }

                sourceNode = sourceNode.TrimEnd(',');

                var targetNode = "";
                foreach (var item in _Node_Neighbor)
                {
                    targetNode += item + ",";
                }

                targetNode = targetNode.TrimEnd(',');

                query = query.Replace("##Source_Node", sourceNode).Replace("##Target_Node", targetNode);

                SqlCommand _myCommand_4 = _con.CreateCommand();

                _myCommand_4.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GraphEdges
                                     WHERE Source_Node IN @Source_Node 
                                     AND Target_Node IN @Target_Node";


                _Mutual_Links = Convert.ToInt32(_myCommand_4.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```