# Retrieve every individual items from the list box and store it as a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

in aspx.cs

```
 string CatID = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            // get the value of the item in your loop
            CatID += li.Value + ",";
        }
    }
```

In aspx

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
    DataTextField="Username" DataValueField="Username" Height="175px" 
    Width="167px"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [login_det] WHERE ([Type] = @Type)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="User" Name="Type" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

A piece of code is shown above which will give the output as `abc,bcd,efg,hig,` when I select four items in the list box. Now is there any possibilities of retrieving these values individually and store it as a string?.Like`

```
string a = “abc”;
String b=”bcd”;
String c=”efg”;` etc.
```

Another conflict occurs is that there may be **100’s of items in the list box**.and if I select 90 items I should declare or assign the each items with a string variable,which is meaningless.But is there any other possibility of storing or retrieving individual items from the list box?

Comment: Number and selected items in a listbox are a run-time thing. Variables are a compile time thing. You're taking wrong approach. I would suggest you show us what you want to achieve...

Comment: i want to store individual selected items as string variable.

Comment: Yes you said but you can't (compile-time, run-time). Explain **why** you want to do that not the way you would like to do it.

Comment: In my list box i have list of `users`.So selection of the user should make me to insert some data to the `individual user` profile.Hence i need the individual records.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<string>` :

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        // get the value of the item in your loop
        result.Add(li.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: "li.Selected == true" is redundant; "if (li.Selected)" is much better

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment you need list of selected items to do some further processing. You don't show your actual code so I'll use a fictional example:

```
// Let me suppose you're using EF to store some data
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    foreach (var li in ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected))
    {
        // I assume you have user ID (as it's name) in the Value property
        // of each ListItem in your ListBox
        string userName = li.Value;

        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == userName);

        // This is not redundant, user may even be deleted in another session
        if (user != null)
        {
            // Do changes you need
            user.HasBeenSelected = true;
        }
    }

    // We're done, apply changes you made
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you see you do not need to create a separate variable for each selected item, you have list of them then you do not need to create another temporary list, just *consume* selected items doing processing you have to do.

Sorry I can't be more specific without some code to inspect, just another example to make intent clear:

```
foreach (var li in ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected))
{
    var user = Membership.GetUser(li.Value);
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.IsLockedOut = false;
        Membership.UpdateUser(user);
    }
}
```

From your example (illustration purposes only!):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ProjectConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    foreach (var li in ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected))
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommantText =
                "UPDATE [Login_det] SET Enabled = 0 WHERE Name = @UserName";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", li.Value);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that if you have  a list of items you may not need to execute multiple commands, you may use a single command with a table parameter. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502873/1207195) here on SO for a good example.

Comment: @ShreyasTg added another example, I still don't know what you have to do (not just where data comes from) but it may be similar to what you're doing (just adapt SQL code...it's just an example, I wouldn't hard-code sql code in that way)

Answer (score 0):

```
string CatID = string.Empty;
int i = ListBox1.Items.Count(); //not sure with this
string[] CatValues = new string[i];
int iCount = 0;
foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
        // get the value of the item in your loop
        CatID += li.Value + ",";
        CatValues[iCount] = li.Value;
        iCount++;
    }
}
```

Then you can loop the CatValues to get all values. I don't know if this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to extract all the selected values and add them to a list, like so:

```
var selectedValues = from ListItem item in ListBox1.Items where item.Selected select item.Value;
var selectedStrings = selectedValues.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection, e.g. `List<String>` to store the values; *Linq* could be very convenient to feed the collection

```
  List<String> result = ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

It's also very easy with Linq to create a *comma separated string* as you've done:

```
  string CatID = String.Join(",", ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Value));
```