# c# datatable how to get all the records with a condition

Tags: c#, datatable

This is my code:

```
SqlCommand vmpCmd = new SqlCommand("sp", connectionstring);
SqlDataAdapter DAvmp = new SqlDataAdapter(vmpCmd);
DataSet DSvmp = new DataSet();
DSvmp.Clear();
DAvmp.Fill(DSvmp);
DataTable table;
table = DSvmp.Tables[0];
```

from that `table` I need to take all the **rows** that its `Campaign` column exists in this list `List<string> compaines = new List<string>();`

#### What have I tried

I tried this:

```
table = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
         where compaines.Contains(row.Field<string>("Campaign"))
         select row);
```

but I got this exception on the `select`:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Data.DataTable'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to a `DataTable` you can use `CopyToDataTable`:

```
var filteredRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => compaines.Contains(row.Field<string>("Campaign")));
table = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

But instead of filtering when you've already retrieved all records   i would do that in the database. [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502866/284240)'s a nice trick to build parameters from a `List<string>`.

Comment: i am trying your solution

Comment: you have changed you code, is my previous code wrong? when I made var and then copytodatatble it works

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: you can always look at the revision-history of a question/answer to see what was changed. The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25380213/revisions) is below the question/answer. In this case i have replaced a colon with a dot and mentioned that you should filter in the database if possible since that is much more efficient if the table is getting large.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method to convert `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to `DataTable`

```
table = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
         where compaines.Contains(row.Field<string>("Campaign"))
         select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the values in `var` data type like this as LINQ returns `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow` which cannot be implicity converted to `Datatable` type

```
var filteredTable = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                     where compaines.Contains(row.Field<string>("Campaign"))
                     select row);
```

Comment: I can't do that because I do this ` table.Compute("Sum(TotalCalls)", "");` when I filter the table

Answer (score 0):

If you want the retrieved records for other operations then its fine otherwise it's better to use filter in your query and for that there are below methods:

1. You can use parameterized query
2. You can build your query string using String.Join() from your List